# How to use role based access in laravel using entrust

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes, entrust

I am using Laravel 5.4. I want to assign all authority to 'Admin' role. But Employee cannot delete or edit records.  I'm using **Entrust** Package for Role based permission.

I've written routes for this but unfortunately Its not working for employee.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => 'auth'], function () {

// Route::resource('plotsize', 'plotSizeController');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:Employee'], function () {
    Route::resource('plotsize', 'plotSizeController', ['except' => 'edit', 'update', 'delete']);
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'role:Admin'], function () {
    Route::resource('plotsize', 'plotSizeController');
}); });
```

This is another approach that I had tried but unfortunately Its also not working.

```
protected $user;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        if(Auth::user()->hasRole('Admin')){
            $this->middleware('role:Admin');
            return $next($request);
        }

        if(Auth::user()->hasRole('Employee')){
            $this->middleware('role:Employee', ['only' => ['edit', 'update', 'destroy']]);
            return $next($request);
        }

    });
}
```

If you're giving me suggestion to use Policy in Laravel. I've tried that but I'm not getting what's the issue on this. Can you provide me any example for this? Thanks

Comment: have you registered the middleware in `app\Http\Kerner.php` ???

Comment: Yes I've registered that

Comment: is it throwing any exception or giving any kind of error message ???

Comment: not getting any error nor any exception.